# ColdFusion integration of KendoUI Scheduler

Tags: coldfusion, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am new to ColdFusion and need to understand how to create a JSON endpoint that I can integrate into a KendoUI Scheduler I would like to add to the page.  I need to have full CRUD functionality to my back-end SQL Server database

Comment: What access do you have to this database now?

Comment: This is much too broad of a question. Narrow it down to a specific issue you are having. Include what you have tried and code samples.